# DISM restore capability removed from WIM copy, using original

Tags: windows, windows-installation, dism, wim

Suppose I was over-eager in pruning my Windows install image:

```
FOR /f %I ('DISM /Image /Get-Capabilities /Format:Table') DO DISM /Image /Remove-Capability /CapabilityName:%I
```

**Can I restore individual elements using a backup of the original WIM?**

I tried this a few different ways using `/Remove-Capability` and then `/Add-Capability`, for the same capability, attempting to use the original `Install.wim` as the "restore" source. I received `Error: 0x800f081f source files could not be found`, but I'm not sure I understand the supported cases of that command. MS documentation says it supports a WIM source, but perhaps that is only true when it contains .CAB files, such as in the Windows FOD ISO from an MSDN subscription I do not have.

If the answer is "no", I'd appreciate a little background on why; such as "the .CAB contains the installation metadata, which is never copied to the WIM", or whatever the case may be.

The specific Capability is probably irrelevant, but I was testing with `Windows.Client.ShellComponents` against a copy of `Install.wim` from the Windows 10 Pro 21H1 ISO.

Comment: Difficult to answer this question without the errors you received.

Comment: @Ramhound reproduced and added the error message

Comment: The error suggests your attempting to remove a capability (feature) that exists on the table but that does not exist on the image on the disk.  In order to confirm that is that the case I would compare the list of features from both sources.

Comment: I received the error when trying to /Add, not /Remove, and I know the feature existed in both because one was a copy of the other.